# javascript limit display link from text area

Tags: php, javascript

i have a following feed from twitter and im making all links clickable and then i want that links which are inside a tag to be short to 30 chars, if its more then 30 chars then show ... after 30 chars

twitter feed

> i need to start learning some real javascript from http://javascript.com/java/codes/snippet/search?q=javascript+limit+chars+leading  some more text here, so dont remove this.

TO

> i need to start learning some real javascript from http://javascript.com/java... some more text here, so dont remove this.

just need to know how can i truncate the inside of  tag.

**Edited**

the link can be anywhere in whole text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate a string, have a look at the trunc-prototype method for strings in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript/1199420#1199420). To acquire all links of a page use:

```
var linksHere = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

loop through your links and shorten the innerHTML of every link if the length is more than you want. Something like:

```
var i=-1,len = linksHere.length;
while (++i<len){
     linksHere[i].innerHTML = linksHere[i].innerHTML.trunc(30);
}
```

Comment: +1. Although I'd keep the loop-housekeeping side-effects outside the condition for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy truncating function I use.

```
// Examples
truncate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'); // returns 'abcdefghijklmnopqrst...'
truncate('hello there', 15); // returns 'hello there'
truncate('hello there', 5, '...read more...'); // returns 'hello...read more...'

// Truncating method
function truncate(string, length, end)
{
  if (typeof length == 'undefined')
  {
    length = 20;
  }

  if (typeof end == 'undefined')
  {
    end = '...';
  }

  if (string == null)
  {
    return '';
  }

  return string.substring(0, length-1)+(string.length > length ? end : '');
}
```

Comment: good helpful function, but im afriad its not for my use yet, because i need to trancate links, which are inside the textarea and not truncate complete text