# Javascript word count cut off

Tags: javascript, blogs, word-count

I have a div with an ID "shortblogpost". I would like to count up to 27th word then stop and add "..." at the end.

I was trying the following code. Problem, Its counting letters and not words. I think its using jQuery and not strait up JavaScript?

I need to use JavaScript for various server reasons only

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit        = 100,
    text         = $('div.shortblogpost').text().split(/\s+/),
    word,
    letter_count = 0,
    trunc        = '',
    i            = 0;

while (i < text.length && letter_count < limit) {
  word         = text[i++];
  trunc       += word+' ';
  letter_count = trunc.length-1;

}

trunc = $.trim(trunc)+'...';
console.log(trunc);
</script>
```

Ty all in advance for any help.

Comment: lodash `truncate` may be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-truncate-long-strings/56973819#56973819).  [doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#truncate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Truncate function.

Use:  truncate('This is a test of this function', 2);
Returns: This is...

Use:  truncate('This is a test of this function', 5, '+++');
Returns: This is a test of+++

```
function truncate (text, limit, append) {
    if (typeof text !== 'string')
        return '';
    if (typeof append == 'undefined')
        append = '...';
    var parts = text.split(' ');
    if (parts.length > limit) {
        // loop backward through the string
        for (var i = parts.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
            // if i is over limit, drop this word from the array
            if (i+1 > limit) {
                parts.length = i;
            }
        }
        // add the truncate append text
        parts.push(append);
    }
    // join the array back into a string
    return parts.join(' ');
}
```

**Edit:** 
Quick and dirty implement by parameters of OP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// put truncate function here...

var ele = document.getElementById('shortblogpost');
ele.innerHTML = truncate(ele.innerHTML, 20);
</script>
```

Comment: Ok again...im trying to emplament your answers but not having much luck...lets say I know nothing about JS (half true :))

Comment: OK, added a quick and dirty implementation.  Though I will also add the caveat that you should try to gain a better understanding of how javascript and HTML work together - undirected poking around is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: CONGRAZ! YOUR CODE WORKED! :)

Comment: the problem was you were using $('div.shortblogpost') on an id where u shoudl have done $('div#shortblogpost');

Comment: Heh, thanks... but in all fairness, so do some of the other answers here.  It isn't a matter of simply writing code that works, but doing so in a way that an inexperienced person can effectively use it!  :)

Comment: undirected poking around is what I do :)
I'm self tough when it comes to JavaScript. Every day I get better at it, but there are some functions still outside of my general knowledge base.

Comment: your right, many of the answers posted here probably would have worked too. To your other point, your code did work for this inexperienced person so..you got the coodos...just accept it already! :)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in one line of code:

```
myString.replace(/(([^\s]+\s+){27}).+/, "$1...");
```

Or, you can make it a function:

```
function truncateString(s, wordCount)
{
    var expr = new RegExp("(([^\\s]+\\s+){" + wordCount + "}).+");
    return s.replace(expr, "$1...");
}
```

So, to make this work for your code, you can do:

```
var post = $('div.shortblogpost').text();  // get the text
post = postText.replace(/(([^\s]+\s+){27}).+/, "$1...");  // truncate the text
$('div.shortblogpost').text(post);  // update the post with the truncated text
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong

<script type="text/javascript">
shortblogpost.replace(/(([^\s]+\s+){24}).+/, "$1...");
</script>

but thanks for what seems like a short sweet answer

Comment: I like the cut of your jib.  I can't crank out accurate regex without much hesitation and testing.

Comment: @webmaster alex - I've updated my answer to provide more specific code.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I made this comment, please let me know if it effects your code...........

[the text is in the following <div id='shortblogpost'>" + data.entries[i].excerpt + "</div> further down the page I added your JS to then take the results and shave it down. I assumed it would pop the outcome back into the correct div]

Answer (score 1):

The loop is appending word by word, while (there are words && the letter count is lower than a limit). The only thing you need to do is replace the second condition with "&& the word count is lower than a limit".

Converting this pseudocode to JS should be trivial...

Comment: Well, your answer seems simple...but i was given the code I started with. While I endeavor to learn more JS on my own im not yet at the point where I can implement your answer on my own.

Comment: @webmaster alex l: Well, `i` seems to be holding the number of words you currently have in `trunc`...and there's a `limit`...and you're trying to find out if one is larger than the other...

Answer (score 1):

How about this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5spJb/3)

html:

```
<div id='shortblogpost'>test test test test test test test test test test test</div>
```

javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('shortblogpost').innerHTML);
var numWordToDisplay = 3; //how many words u want to display in your case 27
var newArray = document.getElementById('shortblogpost').innerHTML.split(' ');
if(newArray.length >= numWordToDisplay )
    newArray.length = numWordToDisplay;
console.log(newArray.join(' ') + '...'); //test test test...
```

Comment: lol, I ty for editing, Im testing your answer now and your prior post didnt work :/... trying new edit

Comment: are the text inside of the div#shortblogpost?

Comment: Can you do me a favor, its not working yet but can you add an alert pop to the getElementByID to see if its finding my shortblogpost.

Im certain the problem is on my end and not with your code, but Id like to check.

Comment: the text is in the following

<div id='shortblogpost'>" + data.entries[i].excerpt + "</div>

further down the page I added your JS to then take the results and shave it down. I assumed it would pop the outcome back into the correct div

Comment: There you go.  Is your shortblogpost similar to what i post for html?

Comment: what is data.entries[i].excerpt?  probably want to do the javascript onload or ondomready

Comment: Just try to eliminate variables on my end I did the following...still no joy..............
------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function Func1Delay()
  {
  setTimeout("Func1()", 3000);
  }
  
  function Func1()
  {
   alert("Delayed 3 seconds");
   var post = $('div.shortblogpost').text();  // get the text
   post = postText.replace(/(([^\s]+\s+){27}).+/, "$1...");  // truncate the text
   $('div.shortblogpost').text(post);
  }
</script>

Comment: go ahead and put up a jsfiddle

Comment: actually the best one is @gilly3 but user experience > best answer imo!

Comment: lol, sad but true, i have to go with what I was able to make work. Maybe/more then likely, the fault was on my end and not with there code so dont hold that against @gilly3's answer, it may work for some ppl. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var words = $('div.shortblogpost').text().replace( /\s/g, ' ' ).split( ' ' );
var result = "";
for( var w = 0 ; w < 27 ; w++ ) {
    if( words[w].length > 0 ) {
        result += words[w] + ' ';
    }
}
result = result.trim() + "...";
```