# Read more button to Category description after certain about of characters.

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to add a read more function to my category description page when the description reaches a certain amount of characters a 'Read more' button appears which on click will slide down the rest of the content.

I'm aware I could use the jQuery slide function, I'm just a little confused how i'd work out the amount of characters or if there is an easier way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Can you show us your code or researches? Maybe a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you can try a combination of css and javascript:
see this for help
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow_hover

or just count the caracters and split all by javascript
see here for help:
[Javascript word count cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962664/javascript-word-count-cut-off)