# How can i get the displayed Text as it is shown in JS

Tags: javascript, text

I want to read out a text width JS on a website as it is shown not how it is delivered by PHP or anything else.
e.g. 
delivered text:

```
ABCDE
```

rendered text (that I want to have):

```
AB
CD
E
```

Does anybody know a way ?

thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the php line that print ABCDE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have read what you're asking correctly but are you talking about displaying code as text on a page? If so you should be able to use the `<pre> </pre>` HTML elements to do this.

Comment: pre is deprecated - perhaps a span with mono spaced font?

Comment: Aha so it is! Didn't realise, you can use <code> tags though, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_phrase_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

A generic function to split up a string into chunks of [n] characters, using a [splitter]:

```
function splitByX(str,n,splitter){
     n = n || 2;
     splitter = splitter || ' ';
     var x = [];
     for (var i=0;i<str.length;i+=n){
        x.push(str.slice(i,i+n));
     }
     return x.join(splitter); 
}
var strFormatted  = splitByX('ABCDEFGHIJ')    //=> "AB CD EF GH IJ"
   ,strFormatted2 = splitByX('ABCDEFGHIJ',3); //=> "ABC DEF GHI J"
   ,strFormatted3 = splitByX('ABCDEFGHIJ',3,'<br>'); 
       //=> "ABC<br>DEF<br>GHI<br>J"
```

For a `<span>` with the text within:

```
var receivedSpan = /*[retrieve the span using a DOM method]*/;
receivedspan.innerHTML = splitByX(receivedspan.innerHTML,2,'<br>');
```

Alternatively you can style the span in PHP:

```
<span style="white-space:pre">AB\nCD\nE</span>
```

Comment: sorry the spacings are line breaks. the original text is without any line breaks, but the browser renders it with line breaks. i want to grab the text generic from the browsers view. The text is embedded in a span

Comment: Then your question is not really clear. You receive `<span>AB\nCD\nE</span>` from the server (PHP) and want to render it with line breaks?

Comment: I edited the answer, the last function now uses a `splitter` argument. Edited your question too, to clarify it.

Comment: @Kooilnc
No. I receive from the Server `<span>My text without line breaks</span>`. The Browser renders it to `<span>My text\nwithout\nline breaks</span>`. I want to read out from the browsers view (with the line breaks). The \n are symbolic for what the CSS does with word-wrapping.

Comment: Ok i want to get more congrete:
the span itself where the text is in, has overflow:hidden text-overflow:clip style. I want to cut off the last displayed 4 characters and append " ..." instead. Do you know for that a way. Thank you for help.

Comment: That's a totally different question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript/1199420#1199420

Comment: Does this script also handle multiple lines ? so that you can get for example 2 line where the second line has the three dots ?

Comment: It handles a string. If you want it to handle lines, i.e. multiple strings, you should code something around it. Please try thinking for yourself. If you want to continue this new question, add it as a new question to SO, or better still, try searching SO for answers, they [the answers] are very likely already given.