# How to replace specific count of characters?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [smart way to shorten long strings with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript)

I have

```
<h1>"Very big" page title </h1>
```

page title and I need to check if character count is bigger than 30, than replace last characters with `...`

Can I somehow split text in two parts and replace second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code may be like this:

```
var text = $('h1').text();
if(text.length > 30)
   $('h1').text(text.sustring(0,30) + "...")
```

and no need for regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check title's length with `jQuery`. If it is greater than `30`, split it to the specified length and add `...` in the end.

`Regex` is useless here.

```
$('h1').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  if ( text.length > 30 ) {
    $(this).text( text.substring(0, 30) + '...' );
  }
});
```