# Shorten long strings in HTML/JS with ellipses

Tags: html

I have a TEXTAREA on my website that can contain a multi-line address (taken from an sql db), but unless the user hovers over it, I would like to just display the first 3 lines of it and then ..., like so:

```
123 Fake St
Fakenshire 
Fakesford...
```

Is this the best way of doing this? I can figure out the roll over, it's the shortening I'm worried about.

[smart way to shorten long strings with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript)

Comment: You could just set a `max-height` on the textarea and then on rollover, you could remove the `max-height` using Javascript.

Comment: The correct name for the 3 dots is 'ellipsis', plural 'ellipses'.

Comment: If you set `rows=3` on the `textarea` element, it will show 3 lines of text, and the rest is available via scrolling. If you wish to replace this normal mechanism by something different, you probably should not be using `textarea` but some other markup.

Comment: What other markups would you recommend?