# Adding ellipsis in the end of truncated text

Tags: css

I have a text that needs to be truncated in some defined length (say 14) and I want to add an ellipses to the end of the truncated text.

Example Output:

*Some text here...*

Can this be done in CSS?

Comment: Did you searched on google before asking this?

Comment: Found it! I found my answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript.

Comment: No @JohnRoca , this task is better to make in css, **not javascript!**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working

Comment: `@mixin ellipsisMe {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.selector {
   @include ellipsisMe;
}`

Answer (score -2):

Css dont know the number of characters. It only knows box model. In a project i had worked on elipses with css but it is worst idea. 
For a better approach use javacript.

Comment: In the real world, it's exactly the opposite. Is better to use CSS for this purpose, not count the characters of an string (each character is different size / weight than others)

Comment: @Tahir Thank you for your answer. But I was looking for a CSS Solution.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I agree with your idea that CSS is better to use rather than using JS for adding ellipses on a truncated String.

Comment: For using css approach you cannot count characters

Comment: @TahirShahzad I was not able to count the characters Yes. But the container has its own width so I thought counting the character would suffice. Anyways. My Question was answered. Thank you for your answer.