# String protoype function not working anymore

Tags: javascript

I have this function taken from here: [smart way to shorten long strings with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript)

```
String.prototype.trunc = String.prototype.trunc ||
  function(n){
      return (this.length > n) ? this.substr(0, n-1) + '&hellip;' : this;
  };

var randNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000000000000));
randNumb = randNumb.toString();
randNumb = randNumb.trunc(16);
```

Today when i tried to use my webpage i got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: randNumb.trunc is not a function
at main (displayData.js:53)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

It worked fine yesterday and i haven't changed this part of the code since then.
Does anyone have an idea what has happened?

Edit:
I found the problem... I apparently changed some code without meaning to. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: `randNumb` is typeof number?

Comment: Where do you get `randNumb`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: i get the number from Math.random() and then randNumb = randNumb.toString();

Comment: Can you post more code???

Comment: "It worked fine yesterday and i haven't changed this part of the code since then" — This type of problem is usually caused by changing something without meaning to. Creating an [mcve] will usually help you identify the problem.