# Is there a way to clip a string in a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im very new to jquery but im using the following code:

```
var lineParts = [];
$.each( chartData, function(k,v){
barParts.push({
    label: k,
    value: v
  });
});
```

How do I clip k to the first 3 characters of the string? For example I want Positive to become Pos. Ive tried using this but with no joy:

```
var lineParts = [];
$.each( chartData, function(k,v){
k = k.substring(0,3);
lineParts.push({
    label: k,
    value: v
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error you getting with k = k.substring(0,3); ?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript

Comment: I do not think its a duplicate answer as OP has done correct steps and the only mistake was in the function parameter for $.each

Comment: @DanielA.White That's not a duplicate.  The issue here is shortening a string *while* parsing an array of data.

Comment: Yes, it is not duplicate. The code was incorrect that is why the OP was not getting the substring. Check my answer, it does as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You have mistaken `function(k, v)`. It should be `function(v,k)`,i.e `(value, key)`

```js
var lineParts = [];
var chartData = ['positive','negative'];
$.each( chartData, function(v,k){
k = k.substring(0,3);
lineParts.push({
    label: k,
    value: v
  });
});

console.log(lineParts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = 'Positive';
var b = a.slice(0,3); // b == 'Pos'
```

This is how you get required number of characters at the start of the string

Comment: Not gonna down-vote as you're right, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Archer the question asked is "How do I clip k to the first 3 characters of the string? ". The rest of the jQuery code is irrelevant to the string manipulating nature of the question, imho.

Comment: The code he posted clearly shows how to do that already, so that is not the question.  If you think the question is worded badly then you should comment on that, rather than posting an irrelevant answer.