# How to set max length in text

Tags: php, html, css

How to set max length from a text and end it with `...`?

I already tried `substr`, but it just cut first and last text.

What I want is, for example I have a `div` with `width: 500px` and `height: 500px`

when the text exceed height, text will cut with `...`.

[image]

I want like this

[image]

I tried like this but, text will cut when exceed width not height.

I used following **css** :

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript** way

Check this answer [smart way to shorten long strings with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript)

**PHP** way

I use this php helper function before sending text to browser:

```
function readMoreHelper($story_desc, $chars = 100) {
  if (strlen($story_desc) <= $chars)
    return $story_desc;
  $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);
  $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));
  $story_desc = $story_desc." ...";
  return $story_desc;
}
```

So, in your handler you could pass your text as below

```
readMoreHelper($yourLongText, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

With **CSS** you can use :

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 3; //number line allow
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
```