# I want to truncate a text from one of the elements of my array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table news:

```
export class News{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  text: string;
  admin: boolean;
  users: Users;
 }
```

I have a method which returns the list of news.ts:

```
news: News[];
pageNews: News[];

getNews(): void {   
//let MaxLength = 5;
this.newsService.getnews().subscribe(res => {
    this.news= res;
    this.pageNews= this.news.slice(0, 10);
 }
);}
```

in news.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="border: none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="title-column">Id</td>
            <td class="title-column">Name</td>
            <td class="title-column">Text</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
       <tr *ngFor="let u of pageNews">
            <td class="row-mid">{{u.id}}</td>
            <td class="row-mid">{{u.name}}</td>
            <td class="row-mid">{{u.text}}</td>
       </tr>                  
</table>
```

but when the name or text are too long, my table overflows, so, I would like to truncate my name and my text when it exceeds 20 characters and put points afterwards.
Example:

```
string s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
result = 'aaaaaaaa...'
```

I try in my news.ts but it does'nt work

```
news: News[];
pageNews: News[];

getNews(): void {   
//let MaxLength = 5;
this.newsService.getnews().subscribe(res => {
    this.news= res.filter(e=>{e.name= e.name.substring(0,20) + '...',
    e.text= e.text.substring(0,20) + '...';});
    this.pageNews= this.news.slice(0, 10);
 }
);}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart way to truncate long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-truncate-long-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform(source: string, size: number): string {
   return source.length > size ? source.slice(0, size - 1) + "…" : source;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use bootstrap 4 class `text-truncate`

```
<span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way to go would be using CSS to "cut" the content. Set `max-width` on the columns and correct text overflow values:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

You will keep your data and get a nice, dynamic truncation.

**Edit**

If you still want to edit your data, I recommend using `substr` in your subscription like so:

```
this.newsService.getnews().subscribe(res => {
  this.news= res;
  this.pageNews = this.news.slice(0, 10).map((post) => {
    return {
      ...post,
      name: post.name.substring(0, 10) + '...'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I would like to modify the text or name coming from my comic strip through my .ts file

Comment: Thank you very much, suppose I want to modify an element of my array, my form, will take the name or the text with '...' instead of the original value

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a angular pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

the code may look some thing like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'StringTrunctuater'})
export class StringTrunctuaterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.slice(0,20)+"...";
  }
}
```

and use like so:

```
<td class="row-mid">{{u.text| StringTrunctuater}}</td>
```

Comment: May be a good idea to add an optional length and offset parameters, by far the best (and most dynamic) answer

Comment: how we use it overall, it's a new class that we have to create?

Comment: @CedricTegue see the link to angular docs I embedded. A pipe is kinda like a helper function, they can be really useful. But in short, you need to create a  new pipe in the cli "ng g pipe".

Comment: thank you, but your method transform() is not correct?!

Comment: indeed. edited and fixed. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-piqqkz?file=app%2Fstring-trunctuater.pipe.ts) is the example running.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to just use css with.

```css
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Here is my really long text that I do not want to show</p>
```

Comment: I would like to modify the text or name coming from my comic strip through my .ts file

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string if the length is exceeding your threshold
[String slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

You can append the dots by string concatenation

Example:

```
var str = "Hello world!"; 
var res = str.slice(0, 5);
res = res + "...";
console.log(res); <<< prints ""Hello..."
```