# Multiple lines text-overflow with unshrinkable item (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is what I am trying to do ↓

[image: what i am trying to do]

And this is what I have (basically, I will no achieve text-overlfow like that, but at least it'll be something. Unfortunately even that doesn't work):

```css
.parent {
  max-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
  
.long {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.short {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="long">Some long long long long long really long text</span>
  <span class="short">short text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't look like a flex job, you probably have to truncate the long text via js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier comment turned in an answer with an example to demonstrate it:

> doesn't look like a flex job, you probably have to truncate the long text via js

here is an example inspired from : [Smart way to truncate long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-truncate-long-strings) ( read answers to go further)

```js
// set your var 
let lgtxt = document.querySelector(".long");
let n = 40;

//function to do the job 
function truncate(str, n) {
  return (str.length > n) ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : str;
}


//fire it once content is loaded
window.onload = function() {
  let str = lgtxt.textContent;
  lgtxt.textContent = truncate(str, n);
};
```

```css
.parent {
  max-height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:justify;
  padding:0 0.25em;
}

.short {
  color: lightgray
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="long">Some long long long long longlong long long longlong long long long really long text</span>
  <span class="short">short text</span>
</div>
```

Flex will not help you here :(

Comment: Oh thank you! The reason why I was trying to use `flex` it's `flex-shrink` property (set that property with 0 for `.short`). But I guess your solution is one of the best even if it's not that accurate how I wish for. I'll wait a bit and if there won't be better solution I'll mark your comment as one that solved me problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so theirs any need to use flexboxes.
If you just want truncatinated text, you can do that using Javascript like this.

**HTML code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS truncates a string</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
text_truncate = function(str, length, ending) {
    if (length == null) {
      length = 100;
    }
    if (ending == null) {
      ending = '...';
    }
    if (str.length > length) {
      return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  };
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.'))
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.',19))
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.',15,'!!'))
```

**Sample output**

```
We are doing JS string exercises.
We are doing JS ...
We are doing !!
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. you will have same result.

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}

.long {
  text-indent: 25px;
}

.short {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="long">Some long long long long  <br /> long really long text...<span class="short">short text</span></span>
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `max-height: 40px;`  so that's why your content is overflowing from `.parent` after 40px

If you want your background-color to wrap the whole content, remove `max-height: 40px;` that would be all.

And if you want that space at the starting, use CSS pseudo-element `::first-letter` as it is in the example below or you can use `text-indent: 20px;` as well

```html
<style>
  .parent {
    /* max-height: 40px; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff
  }

  .long {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    /*text-indent: 25px; you can use this too*/ 
  }

  .long::first-letter { /*if you use text-indent, remove this*/
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .short {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>


<div class="parent">
  <span class="long">Some long long long long long really long text</span>
  <span class="short">short text</span>
</div>
```

And if you want all the texts to be in one line, like your example, you should wrap all the texts in one element, and wrap the short-text with an inline element like `span` or `a` as it is in the example below-

```html
<style>
  .parent {
    /* max-height: 40px; */
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff
  }

  .long {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .long::first-letter {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  .short {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    color: #ddd
  }
</style>


<div class="parent">
  <p class="long">Some long long long long long really long text ...<span class="short">short text</span></p>
</div>
```